# WPF Datagrid Column Header Footer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am using WPF data grid. I want to utilize last column which is just above the scroll viewer.

something like this [image]

I want to add ~F in that highlited column. Note that this should not be another column. I can add as another column but that will no suffice my requirement.

Thanks

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it can help, but way not simply adding a label  that will display on top of the datagrid? 
Just make sure that the Label is connected to the right size of the DataGrid container.

Just an idea (code is conceptual - not working)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Col="0" Grid.ColSpan="2"...../>
    <Label Grid.Col="1" Content="F%" />
</Grid>
```

That way, your dataGrid will take 2 columns, and the label will display on top of the datagrid, but in the 2nd column